# AsyncTask: How do I handle the results from DoInBackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, preferenceactivity

I have a PreferenceActivity that gets its data from a web service(Call forward Numbers, Voicemail status etc)

The class looks like this :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
UserController userControl;
ListPreference lp;
public SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    userControl = new UserController(getParent());
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);

    new PullNumbersTask().execute();

}

   private class PullNumbersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]>
{
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    private String[] numbers;
    private boolean vmStatus;
    private String[] cfInfo;
    public PullNumbersTask()
    {
         Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
         Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    }


    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        Dialog.setMessage("Henter brugerindstillinger..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
        numbers = userControl.GetNumbers(); // Returns a String array containing available numbers
        Dialog.setProgress(30);
        vmStatus = userControl.GetVoicemailStatus(); // Returns a boolean containing voicemail status(enabled/disabled)
        Dialog.setProgress(80);
        cfInfo = userControl.GetCallForwardInfo(); // Returns a String array containing Call forward info.
        Dialog.setProgress(100);

        return null;
    }



     protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
     {
        lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("shownumber_list");
        lp.setEntries(result);
        lp.setEntryValues(result);
        Dialog.dismiss();
     }

}
```

I decided that I want a single AsyncTask call to perform all my web service calls - But how do I Set the data of my preferences onPostExecute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `String[]` as return value from the `doInBackground()` method, define a class inside your `AyncTask` with the fields you need to be passed to the `onPostExecute()` method.

Moreover you should avoid updating the progress dialog directly from the `doInBackground()` as it will not be performed in the UI thread. The `AsynClass` provides the possibility to pass a parameter to a `onProgressUpdate()` method to reflect changes in the progress of background execution.

More details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

What **doInBackground** returns will passed as argument to **onPostExecute**.

So get your preferences from Web Services in **doInBackground** and just return it as string Array.

**onPostExecute** will have that String Array as argument. Apply preferences then.

Comment: As you can see in doInBackground I am getting two string arrays and a boolean returned from the UserController. And as such simply returning a String array wouldnt work.